# postal code input with only numbers(limited 5 ) l Angular 4/5

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I wanted to do an input with that numbers but I do not arrive if I put the type of input to text I can put 5 character alpha numeric and if I put the type of input to number I can put only numbers but it is not limited to 5 numbers
Thank you all

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="number" name="postalCode" placeholder="Saisissez le code postal" formControlName="postalCode" maxlength="5" class="a-textbox"  pattern="/^(([0-8][0-9])|(9[0-5]))[0-9]{3}$/" />
```

Angular

```
postalCode: new FormControl('', [Validators.maxLength(5)]),
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What html5 form attribute should be used for a zipcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676778/what-html5-form-attribute-should-be-used-for-a-zipcode)

Comment: hi fabio ,sorry i don't understand your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution

I have create a demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/postal-code-input-with-only-numberslimited-5--l-angular-45?file=src%2Fapp%2Fonly-number.directive.ts)

> html code

```
<input type="text" OnlyNumber id="number" name="postalCode" placeholder="Saisissez le code postal" formControlName="postalCode" maxlength="5" class="a-textbox" />
```

> OnlyNumber attribute directive

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[OnlyNumber]'
})
export class OnlyNumberDirective {

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

    @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        let e = <KeyboardEvent>event;
        /* 
            8 -  for backspace
            9 -  for tab
            13 - for enter
            27 - for escape
            46 - for delete
        */
        if ([8, 9, 13, 27, 46].indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1 ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (e.keyCode === 65 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+C
            (e.keyCode === 67 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+V
            (e.keyCode === 86 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+X
            (e.keyCode === 88 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
            // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
            // let it happen, don't do anything
            return;
        }
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }

    @HostListener('paste', ['$event']) blockPaste(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        this.validateFields(event);
    }
    validateFields(event) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            let numberRegEx = /^[0-9]+$/;
            if(!numberRegEx.test(this.el.nativeElement.value)){
                this.el.nativeElement.value = "";
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }, 100)
    }
}
```

Comment: it works but not at 100% because I can type special characters that is forbidden ... in all the keyboard I can only type numbers.! what is the solution @krishna

Comment: this is working fine for me. plz create a demo vedio / GIF for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This directive worked very well for me and has everything that you need to force it to 5 digits only and to exclude number related characters such as period, "e", etc.
I recommend to keep the input as type text, as well, see reasoning here.
[Digit Only Directive in Angular](https://codeburst.io/digit-only-directive-in-angular-3db8a94d80c3)

Angular DigitOnly Directive and Mask Directive
https://github.com/changhuixu/ngx-digit-only